# filterFn Seems to have no effect on WSAPI Query

Tags: sdk, rally, appsdk2

I passed a function as a filter in my WSAPI query, however it seems to have no effect on the results returned. Are there fields which cannot be filtered upon by using this method?

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model        : 'TestCase',
            fetch        : ['TestCases'],
            filters      : [
                function(item) {
                    return item.FormattedID.indexOf('10') !== -1;
                }
            ]
        }).load({
            callback: function(records) {
                //All records returned, no filter applied
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also expected your code to work, but perhaps callback happens before the client side filter is applied. Here is a modified version of the code where the filter is applied and only one record is returned as expected:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    launch: function() {

       var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model        : 'TestCase',
            fetch        : ['FormattedID']
        });
       myStore.load({
            callback: function(records) {
                myStore.filterBy(function(item) {
                   return item.get('FormattedID').indexOf('10') !== -1;
            });
            console.log(myStore.getRange()); //one record
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Nick! This is great but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm not looking to filter the results after I get the store loaded on my side, I'm looking for a way to filter the results server side. Basically what I'm trying to recreate is the 'in' filter operator that the LBAPI offers. Since WSAPI doesn't offer this, I was hoping to implement it by passing a function to the server. It looks like that may not be possible though :(

Comment: You're welcome, Conner. I assume you meant to use Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore if you want to get data from LBAPI.